# Drawing problem in java

Tags: java, draw, paint, repaint

I am a new in java, and I need to implement a paint application, and I'm kinda stuck at the beggining, I managed to draw lines to a JPanel which I added to a JFrame,  but each line drawn resets the entire drawing, and in the draw area remains only the last line drawn. I hope I made myself understood, here his the code:

```
class Shapes extends JFrame {

    public JFrame mf = new JFrame("Paint");
    DrawArea da = new DrawArea();

        JToggleButton lineButton = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon("line.gif"));
        JToggleButton brushButton = new JToggleButton();
        JToggleButton pencilButton = new JToggleButton();
        JToggleButton eraserButton = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon("eraser_icon.png"));
        JToggleButton rectangleButton = new JToggleButton();
        JToggleButton ovalButton = new JToggleButton();

    Shapes() {


        da.setBounds(120, 50, 500, 350);
        da.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        mf.setSize(700, 500);
        mf.setLayout(null);

        lineButton.setBounds(0, 50, 40, 40);
        brushButton.setBounds(40, 50, 40, 40);
        eraserButton.setBounds(0, 90, 40, 40);
        pencilButton.setBounds(40, 90, 40, 40);
        rectangleButton.setBounds(0, 130, 40, 40);
        ovalButton.setBounds(40, 130, 40, 40);

        mf.setBackground(Color.red);
        mf.add(lineButton);
        mf.add(brushButton);
        mf.add(pencilButton);
        mf.add(eraserButton);
        mf.add(rectangleButton);
        mf.add(ovalButton);
        mf.add(da);
        mf.show();
        mf.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("x:" + e.getX() + "y:" + e.getY() + "\n" + "x2:" + e.getXOnScreen() + "y2:" + e.getYOnScreen());
            }
        });
        eraserButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
            eraserButton.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("eraser_icon_selected.png"));
        }
        });
        lineButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
              lineButton.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("line_selected.png"));
        }
        });
        da.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                da.setXvalue(e.getX());
                da.setYvalue(e.getY());



            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                da.setX2value(e.getX());
                da.setY2value(e.getY());
                da.repaint();
            }
        });
        da.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                da.repaint();
                da.setX2value(e.getX());
                da.setY2value(e.getY());

            }
        });

    }
}



public class DrawArea extends JPanel {
    int x1value,y1value,x2value,y2value;

    public int getX2value() {
        return x2value;
    }

    public void setX2value(int x2value) {
        this.x2value = x2value;
    }

    public int getY2value() {
        return y2value;
    }

    public void setY2value(int y2value) {
        this.y2value = y2value;
    }
    public JPanel dra=new JPanel();

    public int getXvalue() {
        return x1value;
    }

    public void setXvalue(int xvalue) {
        this.x1value = xvalue;
    }

    public int getYvalue() {
        return y1value;
    }

    public void setYvalue(int yvalue) {
        this.y1value = yvalue;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paint(g);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.drawLine(getXvalue(),getYvalue(),getX2value(),getY2value());

}
}

    class Paint extends JPanel

{ 

    public static void main(String args[])
            {
               Shapes s=new Shapes();

            }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two solutions. The examples draw rectangles, but the concept is the same for lines.

Comment: Thank you, well I need to implement the pencil and brush tools also, + geom figures so that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Override [paintComponent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29), not [paint()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29).  Read this [tutorial](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/40drawingpanel/10drawingpanel.html).  When a panel needs to be redrawn, you call that *panels* [repaint(](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)) method.

Comment: That is a useful change to make, but it is not the cause of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Paint is called by the window manager any time it considers that area 'unfresh'.  If you do it the way you're doing it right now, you will draw the last line drawn every time.

The proper way to do this would be to make a `BufferedImage` in memory and draw on that.  Then, in the paint method, blit the `BufferedImage` onto the surface.  This also makes scrolling and zooming quite easy to do.

Whenever you perform such an action, invalidate the surface so that the window manager will call the paint method for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are only storing one line, and overwriting it each time, so when the component is repainted, the old one is erased and the new one is redrawn.

The expectation of `paintComponent` and the like is that your implementation will draw EVERY graphical element that you want to appear, each time it is called.

Instead of storing `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, you should make a `LineSegment` class or similar that stores those values. Then, when you paint, you call `g.drawLine()` for each `LineSegment` object that you've stored (presumably in an `ArrayList` or similar). Then, when the component is redrawn, all of your line segments should appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit off topic, but I had a few uncomfortable minutes cause I used update() instead of repaint(). I advice to everyone working with SWING to spend some time checking which methods should handled as thread safe and which ones has to be on EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread) to make sure you won't get some unexpected errors.
[This is a good article about this.](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/swingthreads.html)

Also, at the beginning think through if you want to have an undo/redo system in your app...
If so, than how many steps you want to allow being withdrawn. If you want to allow this feature than you cannot just draw and forget about what you draw last time.
Also it would be not memory efficient to store all the images you draw so far. I'm not an expert and I'm not saying this is the best practice but I would go this way:

I would make two lists.

1. One of them would store the **applied drawing actions**,
2. the other would contain the **withdrawn drawing actions**.

*Drawing action* would be an interface and some class would implement it for each specific kind of drawing action (LineDrawAction, CirceDrawAction...).

When you draw a new line or whatever you would empty the **withdrawn actions** list and add it to the **applied action** list. When someone undo the last action, than I would just remove the last drawing actions from the applied list and would add to the withdrawn list (etc...). Depending on if you want to allow only the last x action to be undone when a list reaches this x limit I would remove the first drawing action from the list or queue and would finally draw to the picture - this means permanent drawing and this cannot be undone.

I hope it's clear and useful even if not a direct answer to your question.